# jquery change select box text color on action

Tags: jquery

I have a simple select:

```html
<select id="sel" name="serchtype" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,1);">
<option value="white" style="color: white;">Type: All</option>
<option value="yellow" style="color: yellow;">Normal</option>
</select>
```

and jquery script that changes select box text color depending on what option value is selected

```js
$('#sel').change( function() {
    var color = $('#sel').val();
    $('#sel').css('color',color);

});
```

the problem is that it changes the select text color only when I click on any object outside select box, however I need that color be changed just I select new option value. is it possible using jquery or should i look for some custom plugin?

more similar question: is it possible to make dropdown menu background in select box transparent?

UPDATE: I am using OPERA v 12  browser, in firefox/chrome no such issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the selects value and using it as colors, but `all` and `norm` aren't really colors are they, so it won't work, you need actual valid color values

```
<select id="sel" name="serchtype" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,1);">
    <option value="green" style="color: white;">Type: All</option>
    <option value="purple" style="color: yellow;">Normal</option>
</select>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fB66K/1/)

and this seems easier

```
$('#sel').on('change', function () {
    this.style.color = this.value;
});
```

Comment: oh sorry, that was typos in option values, i corrected it.  Now you can observe on your FIDDLE the problem i have, if you choose any option it will not change the color until you click somewhere else.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, but again, styling options isn't really cross browser, and it's something that normally shouldn't be done, as you'll never know how it turns out in different browsers

Comment: that's it! I am using Opera(problem here), just checked in chrome/firefox - it works normally.

Comment: btw, what about transparent drop-down list?

Comment: If you're really goint to style a select, it should be replaced with a list (as in UL > LI), and that's what all plugins do, as select elements are tricky, events and styles aren't really cross browser.